# Rounded corners without position relative

Tags: html, css

I want exact piece of code to get rounded corners for this page http://www.freecsstemplates.org/preview/fotofolium/. When I use PIE.htc file, it's working only when I declare position:relative; everywhere I used it & that's disturbing the layout. Can someone suggest code that works without position attribute for that template.

I didn't give moz & webkit but,it's working in others like safari,chrome. I gave only

```
border-radius:5px;
behavior: url("PIE.htc");
position: relative;
```

to make it work in every browser. It's not working only in IE if I remove position attribute even with PIE.htc.I used moz, webkit for border box, maybe so workin with FF, Opera etc.

Comment: [border-raduis](http://www.css3.info/preview/rounded-border/)?

Answer (score 0):

Use `border-radius`

Because IE doesn't support `border-radius`, you can use [CSS3 PIE](http://css3pie.com/). Thats where the PIE.htc came from.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `CSS` declaration for the rounded corners for all browsers, and use an `HTC` for old versions of Internet Explorer.

[Working example](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/76169930/stackoverflow/question/10767421/border-radius-no-position.html) for the div with rounded corners with **no `position` set**!

**CSS**

```
.curved {
    -moz-border-radius:10px;        /* Firefox */
    -webkit-border-radius:10px;     /* Safari and chrome */
    -khtml-border-radius:10px;      /* Linux browsers */
    border-radius:10px;             /* CSS3 */
    behavior:url(border-radius.htc) /* Internet Explorer */
}

.menu_buttons {
    margin: 40px;
    width: 100px;
    line-height: 1.1em;
    float: left;
    vertical-align: middle;    
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
    font: 0.9em Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: pink;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

**EXAMPLE HTML**

```
<div class="menu_buttons curved">.menu_buttons element</div>
```

Download the [border-radius.htc](http://curved-corner.googlecode.com/files/border-radius.htc), and check out the [CSS curved corner Demos and Page](http://code.google.com/p/curved-corner/) .

---

## TESTED ON

**Windows XP Profissional versão 2002 Service Pack 3**

- Internet Explorer 8.0.6001.18702
- Opera 11.62
- Firefox 3.6.16
- Safari 5.1.2
- Google Chrome 18.0.1025.168 m
- K-Meleon 1.5.4

**Windows 7 Home Edition Service Pack 1**

- Internet Explorer 9.0.8112.164211C
- Opera 11.62
- Firefox 12.0
- Safari 5.1.4
- Google Chrome 18.0.1025.168 m

**Linux Ubuntu 12.04**

- Firefox 12.0
- Chromium 18.0.1025.151 (Developer Build 130497 Linux)

Comment: Your example is working fine(except background-color missing getting black), but I don't know why it's not working when I edited the code as you gave.